# Assign permission of the current user to a list item programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, react, typescript

I am making an event web part which is connected to a list of items. When a user attends an event, a json object will be parsed to a txt document that is attached to that particular list item /event. with the user details. However, when an user does not have edit permission, this will not work. In this case I want to give the user edit permissions. I'm using SharePoint online.

I was thinking to use REST API to change the users permissions for that particular list item, but from what I could gather it, seems it only works for groups permission etc and not for the current user. Have I missed something, or do I need to user another kind of method?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the REST call supposed to be made but you'll not be able to call it under the current user if they don't have corresponding permissions.

In your case, I'd recommend using MS Flow and a new SharePoint action - [Grant access to an item or folder](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2019/07/16/assign-unique-permission-with-flow-2-new-out-of-the-box-actions/).